# Precondition check failed when try to create a subscriptions

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

I am implementing InApp Purchases in my react native application, when I try to create a subscription from the google play console, it throws the pre condition failed check error, I am attaching the screenshot for a better understanding.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apNlA.png). any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fill out your billing info on `Setup > Payments profile` from the lateral menu in Google Play Console.